# Scrape View More Results with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I scrape hidden products through the view more button or scroll down with bs4? In my case, I'm trying to scrape all search results from the link below, but I'm only able to scrape 20 books, even if there are more than 20 books. How do I get all the search results in this case, and how can I do it on other sites that do the same thing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from Book import Book
import requests

class BertrandScrapper:

    def get_prices(self, title,author):
        page = requests.get('https://www.bertrand.pt/pesquisa/'+(str(title)+" "+str(author)).replace(" ","+"))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        titles=soup.findAll(class_='title')
        for a in titles:
            print(a.text.strip())
        print(len(titles))
```

https://www.bertrand.pt/pesquisa/os+maias+e%C3%A7a+de+queiroz

Comment: You'd have to make the page load more than 20 books. You can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for that.

Comment: I'm trying not to use selenium on this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages are loaded with a `post` request to `https://www.bertrand.pt/pesquisando`. You can retrieve all titles like this:

```
import requests

def get_results(page_nr):
  data = {
    'requestArea': '',
    'pagina': str(page_nr),
    'palavra': 'os+maias+e%C3%A7a+de+queiroz',
    'filterKey': '',
    'filterValue': '',
    'filterName': '',
    'filterMap': '',
    'filterOperation': '',
    'filterField': '',
    'filterOrder': '',
    'tab': 'livros'
  }

  response = requests.post('https://www.bertrand.pt/pesquisando', data=data)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  titles=soup.findAll(class_='title')
  return [a.text.strip() for a in titles]

page_nr = 1
titles = []

while True:
  print("checking page nr", page_nr)
  title_results = get_results(page_nr)
  if not title_results:
    print("No more results")
    break
  else:
    titles.extend(title_results)
    page_nr = page_nr+1
```

result `titles`:

```
['Os Maias', 'Reler Eça de Queiroz', 'Os Maias', 'Os Maias', 'Maias\n\n\n(eBook)', 'Maias', 'Os Maias', 'MAIAS (OS) QUEIROZ, ECA DE', 'Os Maias', 'Os Maias', 'Os Maias\n\n\n(eBook)', 'Os Maias de Eça de Queiróz', 'Os Maias', 'The Maias', 'Os Maias\n\n\n(eBook)', 'Os Maias', 'Os Maias', 'Os Maias', 'Os Maias - Antologia Ilustrada', 'The Maias, The', 'Os Maias  - Volume Ii', 'Os Maias - Volume I', 'Os Maias - Vol. 1 e 2', 'Os Maias - O Realismo']
```

Answer (score 1):

The page is doing Ajax requests, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can simulate these Ajax requests with this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


params = {
    "requestArea": "",
    "pagina": 2,
    "palavra": "os maias eça de queiroz",
    "filterKey": "",
    "filterValue": "",
    "filterName": "",
    "filterMap": "",
    "filterOperation": "",
    "filterField": "",
    "filterOrder": "",
    "tab": "livros",
}

headers = {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

url = "https://www.bertrand.pt/pesquisando"


i = 1
for page in range(1, 3):
    params["pagina"] = page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=params).content, "html.parser"
    )
    for t in soup.select(".title"):
        print(i, t.get_text(strip=True))
        i += 1
```

Prints:

```
1 Os Maias
2 Reler Eça de Queiroz
3 Os Maias
4 Os Maias
5 Maias(eBook)
6 Maias
7 Os Maias
8 MAIAS (OS) QUEIROZ, ECA DE
9 Os Maias
10 Os Maias
11 Os Maias(eBook)
12 Os Maias de Eça de Queiróz
13 Os Maias
14 The Maias
15 Os Maias(eBook)
16 Os Maias
17 Os Maias
18 Os Maias
19 Os Maias - Antologia Ilustrada
20 The Maias, The
21 Os Maias  - Volume Ii
22 Os Maias - Volume I
23 Os Maias - Vol. 1 e 2
24 Os Maias - O Realismo
```